# In HTML, is the document type declaration an element?

Tags: xml, html, w3c

In HTML, is the document type declaration an element?

I guess no, because in XML, the document type declaration `<!DOCTYPE` is part of the prolog and  not an element. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-doctypedecl and https://stackoverflow.com/a/55796040/156458

But The Definitive Guide to HTML5 by Adam Freeman says

> The DOCTYPE element tells the browser it is dealing with an HTML
>   document. This is expressed  through the HTML boolean attribute:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML>
> ```

Comment: Based on the language of the quote you included, it may be considered an element. However, you can't retrieve a reference to it using `document.getElement*`. You can view the value with `document.doctype`, but you can't change it.

Comment: " it may be considered an element" in what way?

Comment: It is only an element in that it uses angle brackets and has attributes. Some (such as Adam Freeman) may consider it an element, but others may not. The [spec on doctype](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#the-doctype) does not call it an element, and it lists elements separately in the next section. Also, it cannot be changed by JavaScript, like all other elements can, and it is parsed separately from all other elements. So I'm inclined to say that it is technically not an element.

Comment: The doctype isn't an element, the "HTML" part isn't an attribute, boolean or otherwise, and the doctype doesn't tell the browser that it's dealing with an HTML document. Apart from that, the statement is pretty accurate.

Comment: @Alohci "the doctype doesn't tell the browser that it's dealing with an HTML document". What does it tell?

Comment: Whether the browser should use standards mode or quirks mode.  It's the HTTP content-type header that tells the browser what sort of document it's dealing with.

Comment: @Alohci What is "standards mode or quirks mode"?

Comment: @Tim - Basically, quirks mode allows browsers to deviate from the standards in a number of ways so that they show old web pages more as they were intentionally intended to work. [MDN: Quirks Mode and Standards Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) explains the difference well.

Answer (score 7):

### No

In no precise, standards-oriented language is a DOCTYPE referred to as an *element*.

*The Definitive Guide to HTML5*, despite its aspirational name, is being sloppy with terminology.

**XML**

The grammar for [**doctypedecl**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-doctypedecl)

```
doctypedecl ::= '<!DOCTYPE' S Name (S ExternalID)? S? ('[' intSubset ']' S?)? '>'
```

is clearly distinct of, and incompatible with, that of [**element**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-logical-struct):

```
element   ::= EmptyElemTag | STag content ETag  
STag      ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
Attribute ::= Name Eq AttValue
ETag      ::= '</' Name S? '>'
```

**HTML5**

The HTML5 specs have separate sections for  DOCTYPEs ([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-doctype) / [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#the-doctype)) and elements ([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#elements-2) / [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements)) and never mangle terminology in any way that confuses DOCTYPEs with elements.

Answer (score 4):

A *document type declaration* is a syntactic construct at the begin of the prolog of a markup document. In SGML, and by extension XML, a DTD tells the parser the document element (name of the "root" element of the document), and optionally contains or references markup declarations for the elements, attributes, entities, notations, short references (SGML only), and link rules (SGML only) used in the document.

An *element*, OTOH, is a logical construct, and formed by begin- and end-element *tags*.

In web browsers, doctype declarations have been used to express HTML version levels in quirky ways in the past, but HTML5 only accepts `<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">`.

In no way can a markup declaration be an element, and `HTML` as used in a doctype declaration isn't an attribute, let alone used as an HTML5-style boolean attribute. The author you cited has absolutely no idea what he is talking about.

Comment: Nice description of purpose and background of the two terms.